# azure network peering zookeeper timeouts

Tags: azure, apache-zookeeper, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying a few things on azure with terraform, but I'm not really used to debug networking and I'm facing an issue.

#### My network looks like :

On_premise_Network(196.168.0.0/16) <--- **VPN IPsec** ---> Gateway Subscription-vnet(10.150.33.0/27).

Gateway Subscription-vnet(10.150.33.0/27) <--- **Vnet Peering** ---> Test Subscritpion-vnet(10.150.33.32/27)

I booted vms on every subscritpion/resourcegroup/subnets to try networking, I can ssh from everywhere to everywhere.

Now I have in my test subscription a zookeeper server.
And I add in that subscription a lenses server to monitor zookeeper.
It works fine.

**My issue is the following :**
I run lenses from my on_premise_network or gateway subscription and it doesn't work.
I see a bunch of *timeout connections* on lenses :

```
 Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 40000ms for sessionid 0x165b40971940005µ
```

And on zookeeper server side I see *Connection reset by peer* :

```
INFO Accepted socket connection from /192.168.4.49:54776 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)

INFO Client attempting to renew session 0x165b40971940005 at /192.168.4.49:54776 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)

INFO Invalid session 0x165b40971940005 for client /192.168.4.49:54776, probably expired (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:357)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1214)
```

What did i do wrong?
(my test vnet has access and is accessible from my on_premise_network through the  subscription's gateway.)

Is there any limitations with vnet peering?

Isn't it making just a flat network?

Why doest it work from within the same subnet and not from out of it?
I need a hand on that, networking isn't clear enough to me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you use vNet peering with the same regions. You can check if the ports need to open in the firewall or NSG associated with the each of peered Vnet for the inbound rules. You can also configure the gateway in the peered virtual network as a transit point to an on-premises network. Ref: [Configure VPN gateway transit for virtual network peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json)

To confirm a vNet peering, you can [check effective routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/diagnose-network-routing-problem) for a network interface in any subnet in a vNet. All subnets within the vNet have routes with next hop type VNet peering for each address space in each peered vNet if the peered Vnet exists. Also, using Network Watcher's [connectivity check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-connectivity-portal?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json) lets you see how traffic is routed from a source virtual machine's network interface to a destination virtual machine's network interface.

If you use Global vNet Peering with different regions, you can not use remote gateways or allow gateway transit. To use remote gateways or allow gateway transit, both virtual networks in the peering must exist in the same region. Besides, remote gateways and gateway transit are currently not supported with global vNet peering. You can [vote on it](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/34324993-global-vnet-peering-remote-gateway-and-gateway-tra) and there will be a plan in the future.

### Update

The errors show that the client tries to reconnect with an probably expired session id. You may refer to [this](http://Client%20reconnection%20after%20a%20connection%20loss) and take a look at the [FAQ](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper/FAQ#A3) for some background.

Comment: Hi, I don't use global peering, it's a local one (westeurope).
My gateway transit is allowed as shown in your example.
The machines are able to reach each other since I can see logs for the failing connection in the logs of each servers...

Comment: Can you check the firewall or NSG which allow the ports 54776 needed to open when you test?

Comment: Give  me a few minutes, the stack was stopped, I'm running my terraforms to rebuild the gateway and the vnets.
I only have NSG on the Vms. And this port is not opened.
Why do i need this port?

Comment: I see your log `INFO Accepted socket connection from /192.168.4.49:54776` and `Invalid session 0x165b40971940005 for client`. It seems invalid session. From your test, I think the network layer connection is working fine, the possible reason is above the network layer. I do not use zookeeper server but you can check if there are ports zookeeper server using.

Comment: aah yep, this port is the port used by my zookeeper's client. And it is opened. And the zookeeper's vm accepts connection from that ip/port

Comment: This helps? issue has been fixed?

Comment: No, I don't think the issue comes from here. These ports are wide open ;)
My stack is running i'm gonna take a look at the effective routes.

Comment: Sadly no. I still can connect from the same subnet, and i've got issues from different one. 
I'm reading more docs about vnets and zookeeper...
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I also update some info about ZooKeeper FAQ in my reply, hope this can help.

Comment: Got something new.
I can reach zookeeper with my client from home and other vnets. 
It just seems to be lenses from landoop that fails reaching the zookeeper. I'll open an issue on their website. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Let's pick/continue this conversation up on landoop / lenses slack channel https://launchpass.com/landoop-community